# C# picturebox location changes when changing image

Tags: c#, location, picturebox

I have a `PictureBox` and when I change the image for some reason the location of the `PictureBox` isn't displayed correctly. It is displayed in the lower left corner instead of the top left.

If I check the values of *top, left, location* etc. it is all correct. Is there something I am forgetting?

```
 myPictureBox.Image = image;
 myPictureBox.Location = new Point(0,0);
```

Comment: Are u using WPF or WinForms? What kind of panel are you using if using WPF? Canvas, Grid, DockPanel?

Comment: I am using WinForms. Picturebox is directly on the form

Comment: Change the SizeMode property to one that suits you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's because the `SizeMode` property is set to `AutoSize`, try to set it to `Normal`.

Good luck!

Comment: PictureBox doesn't have an AutoSize property.

Comment: Thanks seems to have fixed it